# Find where owner OR group does not equal

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix, find

I'm curious if these can be combined into a one-liner:

```
find /var/www/public_html ! -user _www -print0 | xargs -0 chown _www:_www > /dev/null 2>&1
```

and

```
find /var/www/public_html ! -group _www -print0 | xargs -0 chown _www:_www > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Can find look for files and folders not owned by _www in a one-liner? It's not clear to me from the man page if this is possible...

Comment: Side note: you don't need `-print0` and `xargs` here. Just do: `find /var/www/public_html \! \( -user _www -group _www \) -exec chown _www:_www {} +`.

Comment: Excellent tip, making this one-liner even shorter, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just combine the two conditions together with a logical-or:

```
find /var/www/public_html \( ! -user _www -o ! -group _www \) -print0 | xargs -0 chown _www:_www > /dev/null 2>&1
```